# How to set a multiple parameters using String's Controller and RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Hi I need to modify an existent Rest interface. The old Rest interface only take a phone number then look for a record. The phone number used to be unique with the table. Now is the combination of the phone and a number (batchid). So i need to modify the service impl and the client that calls it. Here is the old controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{phone}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public BatchDetail  findByPhone(@PathVariable String phone) {
            return batchDetailService.findByPhone(phone);

        }
```

and here is the how the old client is accesing it:

```
private static final String URL_GET_BATCHDETAIL_PHONE = "http://localhost:8080/Web2Ivr/restful/batchdetail/{phone}";
batchdetail = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_BATCHDETAIL_PHONE, BatchDetail.class, phone);           
batchdetail.setStatus("OK");
restTemplate.put(URL_TO_UPDATE_BATCHDETAIL, batchdetail, batchdetail.getId())
```

;

So my question will be how to modify the controller and the restemplate's client call to support two variables, phone and the number(batchid) something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/Web2Ivr/restful/batchdetail/{batchid}/{phone}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{batchid}/{phone}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public BatchDetail  findByPhone(@PathVariable String phone, @PathVariable String batchid) {
    return batchDetailService.findByPhone(phone);

}
```

Comment: `batchdetail = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_BATCHDETAIL_PHONE, BatchDetail.class, batchid, phone);`?

Comment: if URL_GET_BATCHDETAIL_PHONE is http://localhost:8080/Web2Ivr/restful/batchdetail/{batchid}/{phone} or something similar, yeah that should work.